# How can I connect and combine individual active areas in a geometric shape?

Tags: data, geometry, visualization

I am new in Mathematica and I do not know how I can get the following into a square. I need 4 "active areas" but in a single square which I can easily access and manipulate. Here's what I've done so far:

```
Data = {
FHeight = -2.5; 
FWidth = 10; 
Fdiv1 = FHeight/GoldenRatio; 
Fdiv2 = FHeight/1.2; 
Fdiv3 = FHeight/Pi; 
Fdiv4 = FHeight/(E^2 - 1);
};

a = Graphics[Line[{{0, Fdiv1}, {10, Fdiv1}}], Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, FWidth}, {FHeight, 0}}]
```

[image: 1b]

```
b = Graphics[Line[{{0, Fdiv2}, {10, Fdiv2}}], Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, FWidth}, {FHeight, 0}}]
```

[image: 2b]

```
c = Graphics[Line[{{0, Fdiv3}, {10, Fdiv3}}], Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, FWidth}, {FHeight, 0}}]
```

[image: 3b]

```
d = Graphics[Line[{{0, Fdiv4}, {10, Fdiv4}}], Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, FWidth}, {FHeight, 0}}]
```

[image: 4b]

But I need all of that in a single square with a main independent coordinate system to get 1) the values ​​of the individual areas and 2) the values in the main coordinate system, like this:

[image: 5b]

Everyone tells me that this is easy to do, but I couldn't find anyone that can show me how to do it. That's why I ask the professionals here. Maybe someone here knows how to do it and has a simple solution at hand. I would be very grateful.

Comment: You can combine many primitives under the same `Graphics`. See the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html). Try something like this: `Graphics[{
  Dashed,
  Green, Line[{{0, Fdiv1}, {10, Fdiv1}}],
  Red, Line[{{0, Fdiv2}, {10, Fdiv2}}],
  Cyan, Line[{{0, Fdiv3}, {10, Fdiv3}}],
  Magenta, Line[{{0, Fdiv4}, {10, Fdiv4}}],
  }, Background -> Darker[Gray], FrameStyle -> White, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, FWidth}, {FHeight, 0}}, AspectRatio -> 1]`

Comment: Hi @flinty, yeah that solves my "combination-problem", thanks for that, i didn't know, that i can use the function also "hierarchically", but now i understand the logic behind the function "Graphics" better. But that doesn't solve my other problem, do you have an idea, how i can solve the problem with the two coordinating systems? A little hint would be enough for me, i'll do the rest, because i want to learn it.